# Sort the output of a Borg Backup archive listing

Tags: borg-backup

The command `borg list $REPOSITORY::$ARCHIVE` shows me a list of all files that are contained in a backup archive. That listing is unsorted (apparently).

How can I sort this listing by file name?

This has no effect, despite [documented](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/list.html): `borg list --sort-by name $REPOSITORY::$ARCHIVE`

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe borg's output to `sort`:

```
borg list --short $REPOSITORY::$ARCHIVE | sort
```

Comment: That's going to be hard because the file name comes last in the line. Attributes, owner, size and time come before. So this is the wrong approach.

Comment: @ygoe have you tried my solution? With the ```--short``` option, borg will only print the file/directory names. If you need the other arguments, use the ```--format``` option instead.